# Safari: Closing the movie player window doesn't kill the movie playback

Tags: jquery, iframe, safari, modal-dialog, fancybox

**Background**

I built a site for a film-production client.
They needed a way to demo their showreels to the public and agreed upon a modal `<iframe>` approach (using jQuery and [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)) to showing their reels, all streamed via a third party provider.

You can see the functionality in action here: http://groundglass.co.za/directors/ by clicking on "View Reel" underneath each director photo.

**The Bug**

Try the following:

1. Click 'View Reel'
2. Wait for the video to start playing and then immediately:
3. Close the modal window

At this point, other browsers unload the playing movie, but for some reason Safari carries on playing the video (You can hear the video playing, even if not visible).

**Solution?**

What can I do to get Safari to play nice?
Fancybox has a callback function onClose.  What should I do to the iframe to make it unload?
Trying .remove() doesn't work, one can still hear the audio playing (and could be streaming too - what a waste of bandwidth!)

Thoughts? - Thanks!

--nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the location of the `iframe` to a blank page when the dialog is closed.

Comment: Ahh yes.  Something was wrong with my callback arguement, that explains it :)  Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: to be clearer, onClose I called destroy_iframes() which just set the src attribute to: '#'.

Comment: It pays to be of average intelligence, we come up with easy solutions ;) You smart people think too much. Hehe.

Comment: lol, if I was smart, I'd know not to pass '$.destroy_iframes()' as the callbackOnClose.  Changing it to '$.destroy_iframes' worked.
Changes uploaded.  Thanks again. :)